# Finding block diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone help me with finding the block diagonal form  (so find A with respect to a basis such that $Av_{i+1}=v_i$ and $Av_i=0$) of the following nilpotent 3x3 matrix:
$
\begin{bmatrix}
4 &-4 & 12\\
1& -1& 3\\
-1 &1& -3
\end{bmatrix}
$

Answer (score 1):

It might help to notice that $A=u v^T$, where $u = (4, 1, -1)^T, v=(1, -1-,3)^T$.

Notice that $u \bot v$. This simplifies matters a little.

$\ker A = \operatorname{sp}\{ u, w \}$, where $w=u \times v = (2, -13, -5)^T$, and $u,v,w$ are all orthogonal.

Then $Au = 0, Aw = 0$ and $Av = \|v\|^2 u = 11 u$.

In the basis $\{ u, {1 \over 11} v, w \}$, the matrix $A$ has the form
$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.